# logitech t650 tap to click still not registering?

Tags: touchpad, logitech, xinput, lsusb

I upgraded my firmware as suggested in [this reddit link](http://www.reddit.com/r/Ubuntu/comments/1ys970/logitech_t650_now_with_taptoclick_actions_on_linux/), but I still can't seem to trigger left clicks or right clicks via tapping. Its driving me crazy now as I still need to thumb press the physical click to make the touchpad somewhat usable.

Any thoughts on how I could diagnose what the problem is?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems I needed to update the firmware twice... the correct version is 38.

Tap to click works now

Answer (score 0):

Try running`xev` to see if X is picking up the button presses at all. If it is, it'll just be a matter of binding the key.

Comment: Nope, no event registered. I plugged in the touchpad originally before I updated the firmware... could some config file be cached somewhere in /etc for example? Or does this mean its definitely a firmware problem?